# Encrypted / Decrypting null using DBMS_crypto

Tags: oracle, encryption, null, dbms-crypto

I have search all over the internet for what happened when you encrypt a null value and decrypt it.

So far in my experiment. In my table I have a column that is a timestamp.
I have a few rows of data, in these few rows, I have proper timestamp and null value mixed in.

I attempted this:

```
select count(*) from mytable where key = 'currLoginTime' and
  to_timestamp(clob_substr(decrypt(value,?), 19, 1), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') > ?
```

The first parameter is my private key, and the second parameter is the date I am comparing with.

I keep getting the following exception:

```
ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0;
nested exception is java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01841: (full) year must be
between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0
```

I am guessing that the original null value is getting decrypted to 0. Can someone confirm or shed some light into this? I am really stumped.

Comment: how is clob_substr function defined?

Comment: The null value stays as null, which is easy to demonstrate. Are you sure you're getting the error from the null value, not an actual value? The two obvious things I'd be looking at are whether your `clob_substr` is taking the arguments in the order you expect and returning the portion of the argument you expect; and whether the decrypted value is in the format you expect. Trying to figure it out from the where clause is going to be... tricky. The basic idea should work though.

Comment: I did a more thorough analysis, within the test data set I have, I did have some bad data where the before encrypted value was not valid data. It was from actually 'null' vs null and somehow I over looked that error.

Comment: But you did answer my crucial question of what happen when you encrypt a null. Which you say stay as a null.

Comment: @tbone clob_substr is an oracle predefined function, please google it.

Comment: really?  what package?  I know about dbms_lob.substr, but wasn't aware of "clob_substr".

Comment: @tbone my apologize, I was a little distracted and was looking at my encrypted procedure which was using utl_raw.cast_to_raw and somewhat clob_substr got translated to that in my head. I don't have clob_substr handy but I know there is no foreseeable error in that function since it has been in use for many years by multiple schema throughout the company.

Answer (score 2):

Encrypting or decrypting a null results in a null. It wouldn't make much sense for it to work any other way. To demonstrate:

```
var typ number;
var key varchar2(32);
begin
  :typ := dbms_crypto.encrypt_aes256
     + dbms_crypto.chain_cbc
     + dbms_crypto.pad_pkcs5;
  :key := dbms_crypto.randombytes(32);
end;
/

set null '(null)'

select dbms_crypto.encrypt(src=>utl_i18n.string_to_raw(null, 'AL32UTF8'),
  typ=>:typ, key=>:key) as encrypted
from dual;

ENCRYPTED                    
------------------------------
(null)                         

select utl_i18n.raw_to_char(dbms_crypto.decrypt(src=>null,
  typ=>:typ, key=>:key)) as plain
from dual;

PLAIN                        
------------------------------
(null)
```

The error you are getting is not because of the null values. At least one of your non-null values seems to be invalid - the original plain-text value that was encrypted was not in the format your `to_timestamp()` call is expecting.